# Mysql ROUND function

Tags: mysql, rounding, number-formatting

I'm using Mysql `ROUND` function to round a decimal to 1 decimal but I have a problem... I need to have always one decimal, for example,

```
1280,319 => 1280,3
```

But when I have

```
1283,971 => 1284
```

And I need to have 1284,0

I tried to use `FORMAT(ROUND(1283,971, 1), 1)` but it puts commas as thousand separator and in the example it gives `1,284.0`
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're truncating, not rounding.  Look at [TRUNCATE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-truncate-function.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about specifying a locale to `FORMAT`.

```
select FORMAT(ROUND(1283.971, 1), 1, 'De_de')

# 1.284,0
```

Answer (score 0):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a242/2)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`test` decimal(12,4));

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`test`)
VALUES
    (1280.319),
    (1283.971),
    (1275.521),
    (1256.456);

SELECT  truncate(test, 1)
FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| truncate(test, 1) |
|-------------------|
|            1280.3 |
|            1283.9 |
|            1275.5 |
|            1256.4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not write the number in this format `1283,971`, the comma here uses to separate the parameters.
Try this code: `Select ROUND(1283.971, 1)`